# Photos and videos visible on phone., but impossible to import to a Mac

Tags: backup, 6.0-marshmallow, gallery, motorola-moto-g2, google-plus-photos

I have a Moto G 2nd gen, with android 6 (marshmallow).

It appears that the phone contains some photos and videos which I can see through the Gallery, but I am unable to import to Photos.app on OSX.

The camera app is setup to store images on SD.

I have tried connecting the phone as a camera (PTP) and nothing shows up.
I have also tried connecting the phone as a media device (MTP) and use the android transfer app, but the pictures do not show up in `DCIM/` under "internal storage", and the "sd card" file list doesn't contain a `DCIM/` directory at all.

I have tried wiping the cache partition, ejecting and re-adding the sd card but nothing worked, I cannot find these files. 
Where are they, and how do I get them out of the phone?

Comment: try using apps like shareit which is available both for Mac and Android

Comment: Would solutions involving [ADB](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) be acceptable? Or solutions involving 3rd party apps via WiFi?

Comment: I would say yes, but only if they come with an explanation of *why* it's not possible with standard stuff,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the physical transfer does not work, you could try an app like [WiFi File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer)

It uses your WiFi to transfer files, so that might be worth a try.

Comment: so, file is still invisible in the android transfer app and some others (e.g. airmore doesn't see the folder) but for some reason wififiletransfer shows all the proper directories. Since nobody offered another solution, I'm going to award the bounty to this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
It appears that the phone contains some photos and videos which I can see through the Gallery, but I am unable to import to Photos.app on OSX.
```

From what I understand, you seem to be able to view the photos in your gallery but you're unable to find them when you connect the phone to your Mac. And you seem to be searching them only in DCIM. Are you sure that these photos exist in locations other that DCIM perhaps?

If you're able to view these photos and videos in your phone's gallery, it means that they exist *somewhere* on your device. You could start with figuring out as to where they are. In the gallery, if you tap on info, it should show you the file name and where it's located. Once you chance upon the right location, try navigating to that specific location, maybe via a file explorer. This is to be certain that other generic apps also are able to find these pictures

An immediate solution I could find is:

1. Select those images from the gallery
2. Hit the share button
3. Use the Google Photos app and have it uploaded on to your google photos.
4. Head to photos.google.com on your Mac and download those photos from there.

Note - It doesn't really have to be photos app. You could use just about anything to have it transferred out. Even old-school bluetooth.